# Single button for Gmail to "not spam" and "archive"

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

I find I get quite a lot of legitimate mailing list emails in my spam folder. Usually, by the time I've opened them and determined that they aren't spam, I'm done with them.

I like to mark them as "not spam", but that sends them into the middle of my inbox as read messages. Is there any way to simultaneously archive at the same time?

Comment: If you want to avoid this problem setup a filter and under actions set "Never send it to Spam"

Comment: likewise for "not span" and "delete"

Answer (score 1):

Labs. There's Send and Archive lab:

[image: Send and Archive]

but there isn't a "Not Spam and Archive" lab.

Why don't you [Suggest a Labs Feature](http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/topics?pli=1)?